# Programmatically move an view in android

Tags: android, view

I do n't want to use margin, padding to move a  object. Is there any method , that can move my object.

I'm looking for some thing line Left, Right, Top, Bottom kind of thing so I can pass values
to move the view in my layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an animation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html, just set the animation time to 0.
Remember to use `.setFillAfter(true);`

Comment: :How do i do it using programatically ?

Comment: Try it out, then ask if it doesn't work - I linked you to the docs

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = view.getTranslationX();
view.setTranslationX(val);
```

Works for X, Y, and Z, and X/Y with rotation.